# Regular Expression with multiple words (in any order) without repeat

Tags: javascript, regex, search

I'm trying to execute a search of sorts (using JavaScript) on a list of strings. Each string in the list has multiple words.

A search query may also include multiple words, but the ordering of the words should not matter.

For example, on the string *"This is a random string"*, the query *"trin and is"* should match. However, these terms cannot overlap. For example, *"random random"* as a query on the same string should not match.

I'm going to be sorting the results based on relevance, but I should have no problem doing that myself, I just can't figure out how to build up the regular expression(s). Any ideas?

Comment: How does `trin and is` match `This is a random string`?

Comment: "random random" should match once ? If not I totally don't get it.

Comment: @mellamokb: ThIS IS a rANDom sTRINg.

Comment: You say "without repeat" in the title but the string "is" is repeated in your example: "Th(is) (is) a random string". What do you mean?

Comment: When I say without repeat - I mean "random random" should not match because, even though both words in the query exist, both words match over the same text in the string (and there isn't another part of the string that would match). Complicated requirements, I know ... but hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: `$copy = $string; for $word (split " ", $query) { $copy =~ s/$word// || die }` works in Perl.  Translation into Lavascript left as an exasperize for the reader.

Comment: @tchrist: Are you sure that it works correctly and doesn't give false matches? For example if the string is `abcdef` and the query is `cd be` then I believe it will match it because the string will be changed to `abef` after the `cd` is removed.

Comment: @Mark: You could add spaces then. Or you could remap the matched things into something that can't match. `s/($word)/my $weird = $1; $weird =~ tr[\0-\x{10_FFFF}][\x{20_0000}-\x{3F_FFFF}]; $weird/e`. That leaves it in place but shifts it into a range guaranteed not to be in the original, like flipping the high bit on all ASCII data.

Comment: @tchrist: What about searching the string `abc ab` with the query `ab bc`? I think your solution will not match because I think it finds the first occurrence of `ab`, giving `??c ab` and then searching for `bc` fails. But (as I interpret the question) it should match because of `a(bc) (ab)`.

Comment: @Mark: That's a very interesting point, because it brings ordering into the picture, and also boundaries. Without boundaries, you can end up chopping out parts of words, and the order in which you apply your searches matters. The original problem has `/trin/` matching in `"string"`, so I don’t think they want a `/\b trin \b/x` type of thing. But without that, ordering matters, as an earlier match can invalidate a later one, which wouldn’t occur if ordered differently. Maximizing the matches in any order begins to smell rather like the Travelling Salesman problem as many paths are tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It probably isn't a good idea to do this with just a regular expression. A (pure, computer science) regular expression "can't count". The only "memory" it has at any point is the state of the DFA. To match multiple words in any order without repeat you'd need on the order of 2^n states. So probably a really horrible regex.

(Aside: I mention "pure, computer science" regular expressions because most implementations are actually an extension, and let you do things that are non-regular. I'm not aware of any extensions, certainly none in JavaScript, that make doing what you want to do any less painless with a single pattern.)

A better approach would be to keep a dictionary (Object, in JavaScript) that maps from words to counts. Initialize it to your set of words with the appropriate counts for each. You can use a regular expression to match words, and then for each word you find, decrement the corresponding entry in the dictionary. If the dictionary contains any non-0 values at the end, or if somewhere a long the way you try to over-decrement a value (or decrement one that doesn't exist), then you have a failed match.

Comment: Copy the string into a temp. Delete each word from the query from the temp, or fail. If you haven't failed, you've succeeded.

Comment: We ended up taking an approach somewhat along the lines of what you suggested.

Comment: @tchrist Yeah, that's pretty much what I said, except I said "dictionary" instead of "temp".

Answer (score 5):

The query `trin and is` becomes the following regular expression:

```
/trin.*(?:and.*is|is.*and)|and.*(?:trin.*is|is.*trin)|is.*(?:trin.*and|and.*trin)/
```

In other words, don't use regular expressions for this.

Comment: Regexes are fine.  Consider the Perl solution: `$copy = $string; for $word (split " ", $query) { $copy =~ s/$word// || die }`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm totally not sure if I get you right there, so I'll just post my suggestion for it.

```
var query   = "trin and is",
    target  = "This is a random string",
    search  = { },
    matches = 0;

query.split( /\s+/ ).forEach(function( word ) {
    search[ word ] = true;
});

Object.keys( search ).forEach(function( word ) {
    matches += +new RegExp( word ).test( target );
});

// do something useful with "matches" for the query, should be "3"
alert( matches );
```

So, the variable `matches` will contain the number of unique matches for the query. The first split-loop just makes sure that no "doubles" are counted since we would overwrite our search object. The second loop checks for the individuals words within the target string and uses the nifty `+` to cast the result (either `true` or `false`) into a number, hence, +1 on a match or +0.

Comment: You have to delete it if you find it, and fail if you don't. That way you don't need to store a search array or count things.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a solution to this issue and none of the solutions presented here was good enough, so this is what I came up with:

```
function filterMatch(itemStr, keyword){
    var words = keyword.split(' '), i = 0, w, reg;
    for(; w = words[i++] ;){
        reg = new RegExp(w, 'ig');
        if (reg.test(itemStr) === false) return false;   // word not found
        itemStr = itemStr.replace(reg, '');              // remove matched word from original string
    }
    return true;
}

// test
filterMatch('This is a random string', 'trin and is');   // true
filterMatch('This is a random string', 'trin not is');   // false
```